# Blocking the bluescreen from appearing when ctrl+alt+del is pressed using c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

While my unit test program is running, if I press the ctrl+alt+del the program must stop the blue screen.I tried the following but it didn't work

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "taskmgr.exe"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: Why do you do Unit testing by sending Ctrl+Alt+Del Keyboard commands in the first place?

Comment: you can't bind to ctrl+alt+delete. its handled by the kernel.

Comment: also why are you trying to read the contents of task manager?

Comment: Guys this is my assignment . I am a noob in C#. Is there anyway attaining this using unittest c#. I seriously want to learn it now

Comment: What you ask is not possible and hasn't been for a long time.  Else it would be a security risk

Comment: If this is your assignment then you need to change your course - your instructor has no idea what they're talking about. Unless it's a trick question?

Answer (score -1):

Not understanding why you would think this is a good Idee, however you could get the keys pressed and then do with that what you think you need to do.

The method you're looking for that does all but CTRL+ALT+DEL is:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Control), System.Windows.Controls.Control.KeyDownEvent, yourdelegate);
```

Normally this is something you might find in a virus, it is therefore likely that windows or a antivirus scanner will start blocking your software, can even be that your compiler refuses to generate the exe.

To capture the CTRL+ALT+DEL you would need to capture that from your generated  Keyboard driver, the only reason this can be a assignment is if you're studying at Malware Academy :-)

Comment: You cannot intercept ctrl alt del